# Using Foursquare API in Google Map using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, foursquare

I have tried implementing foursquare API in google Maps can some help me sort out the error which keeps coming....

```
function createMarker(location){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
  position: location.latlng,
  title: location.name,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
   });

  location.marker = marker;

    getVenueDetails(location, function(windowContent){
    infoWindow.setContent(windowContent);
    infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
  });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    getVenueDetails(location, function(windowContent){
    infoWindow.setContent(windowContent);
    infoWindow.open(map, self);
  });
 });
  }
  var baseUrl = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?',
  clientId = '*********************************************',
   clientSecret = '*******************************************';

 function getVenueDetails(location, infoWindowCallback) {
 foursquareUrl = baseUrl + '&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&v=20161207&query=' + Model[location].id + '&ll=11.93,79.82';
 $.getJSON(foursquareUrl)
  .done(function(data){
    var currentVenue = data.response.venues[0];
    var placeName = currentVenue.name;
    var placeAddress = currentVenue.address.formattedAddress;
    var placePhonenos = (currentVenue.contact.formattedPhone === undefined)? 'None': currentVenue.contact.formattedPhone;
   windowContent = '<div id="iw_container"><p><strong>Name: </strong>' + placeName+ '</p>' +
                '<p><strong>Address: </strong>  ' + placeAddress + '</p>' +
                '<p><strong>Phone: </strong>' + placePhonenos + '</p></div>';
   infoWindowCallback(windowContent);
  }).fail(function(error){
    infoWindow.setContent('Fail to connect to Foursquare: ' + error);
  }
  );
   }
```

Here is my repo [map](https://github.com/renurevzranju/map)...
Am getting Error in the API Section that is mainly in the Model[location].id.. I get "id" is not defined error... Any Help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `id` defined in your Model class. Also, you should be passing the venue name to the Foursquare search `query` parameter, not the lat/lng. You should change `Model[location].id` to `Model[name]`.

Try replacing this line:

```
foursquareUrl = baseUrl + '&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&v=20161207&query=' + Model[location].id + '&ll=11.93,79.82';
```

With this:

```
foursquareUrl = baseUrl + '&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&v=20161207&query=' + Model[name] + '&ll=11.93,79.82';
```